# What does "sustain" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is the context:

> think that emotion is very important in our attribution of
>   consciousness to other people and to animals. Computers can compute very complicated things but this
>   ability is not consciousness. Instead, it is the emotional connection to someone (or animal) that gives us the intuition that it is
>   conscious. This is an interesting psychological question: What makes us feel that something is conscious
>   besides ourselves? The answer will include psychology. And whether that psychology can **sustain a science**,
>   I’m very skeptical. The example of the computer or robot fooling me by looking emotional or not fooling
>   me by having true emotion just isn’t **compelling** to me. That’s why I never got quite caught up in this
>   issue.
>
> source: The enigma of human consciousness.New York Academy of Sciences.

What is the meaning of "sustain a science"? Does it mean "stay scientific?"

Additionally, in this context, does compelling mean convincing or captivating? I think is convincing but I want to be sure.

Comment: The author in *NYAS* says that the basis for studying consciousness (outside our own) lies in our intuition, i.e., an examination of our subjective psychological state. The author's claims that this is not enough to maintain ongoing scientific investigation of consciousness, which he phrases as not enough to "sustain a science."

Comment: A topic is **compelling** if it grabs your interest or attention in a powerful way, so powerful, in fact, that resistance is futile. *Convince* means to bring someone to believe the truth of a proposition. You can find the study of extraterrestrial aliens to be compelling without believing they actually exist. *Captivating* has the overtone of one's interest taken by the charm of the subject.